# NSURLConnection Certificate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, ipad

If I have installed a .pfx certificate in a mobileconfig, should I do something when the server ask for it, or does the system take care automatically of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big expert on this topic, but:
pfx certificates are supported for mobileconfig, as explained [here](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_us/enterprise_deployment_guide.pdf), but I believe you have to implement a delegate of NSURLConnection in order to have the handshake done, i.e.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

as already explained on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749429/how-to-use-client-certificate-authentication-in-ios-app).

Then you could take example from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718305/nsurlauthenticationmethodclientcertificate) to find some useful code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is if there is something I have to do when the pfx is in a mobileconfig, outside the app.

Comment: In the third link there is actually a guy with the same issue:
"I'm trying to connect to a server using a .pfx that is stored in a .mobileconfig file on my iPhone." Isn't that the same situation as yours?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the NSURLConnection delegates:
`connection:didReceiveData`,
`connection:didReceiveResponse` and
`connectionDidFinishLoading`.